# Compile error when trying to make rollup apex trigger

Tags: triggers, aggregate, rollup

Been amending a piece of code to suit my needs but it won't compile. My naive eyes cannot see the error of my ways:

```
trigger doRollup on Time_Record__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after     undelete) {

// List of parent record ids to update
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();

// In-memory copy of parent records
Map<Id,Time_Record__c> parentRecords = new Map<Id,Time_Record__c>();

// Gather the list of ID values to query on
for(Daily_Time_Record__c c:Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new)
parentIds.add(c.Time_Record_Link__c);

// Avoid null ID values
parentIds.remove(null);

// Create in-memory copy of parents
for(Id parentId:parentIds)
parentRecords.put(parentId,new Time_Record__c(Id=parentId,RollupTarget__c=0));

// Query all children for all parents, update Rollup Field value
for(Daily_Time_Record__c c:[select id,FieldToRoll__c,Time_Record_Link__c from Daily_Time_Record__c where id in :parentIds])
parentRecords.get(c.Time_Record_Link__c).RollupTarget__c += c.FieldToRoll__c;

// Commit changes to the database

Database.update(parentRecords.values());
}
```

Where:

- Time_Record__c is my parent
- RollUpTarget__c is the place I am trying to roll to
- Daily_Time_Record__c is the child
- Time_Record_Link__c is the link to parent that exists on the child
- FieldToRoll__c is a test field to roll up on the child

I *think* that is what I had to replace from this generic template:

```
trigger doRollup on Child__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
// List of parent record ids to update
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
// In-memory copy of parent records
Map<Id,Parent__c> parentRecords = new Map<Id,Parent__c>();
// Gather the list of ID values to query on
for(Child__c c:Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new)
  parentIds.add(c.ParentField__c);
// Avoid null ID values
parentIds.remove(null);
// Create in-memory copy of parents
for(Id parentId:parentIds)
  parentRecords.put(parentId,new Parent__c(Id=parentId,RollupField__c=0));
// Query all children for all parents, update Rollup Field value
for(Child__c c:[select id,Amount__c,ParentField__c from Child__c where id in :parentIds])
  parentRecords.get(c.ParentField__c).RollupField__c += c.Amount__c;
// Commit changes to the database
Database.update(parentRecords.values());
  }
```

Ideally I want to roll up a sum of 7 fields from the child (hence needing this solution), but starting small.

Comment: Trigger should have been on Child not on Parent. It now saves, but doesn't actually do anything. Can only imagine the SoQL at the end isn't picking up anything to change. Although I cannot imagine how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Yep.

where id in :parentIds]

should have been

where Time_Record_Link__c in :parentIds]

Some testing to do but that should be it.